# backbone js, routing error and url is auto change

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have problem with routing backbone. I call Backbone.history.start() in products index (localhost:3000/products). Routes:

```
'': 'product_index'  
':id': 'product_show' (tag 'a' link 'localhost:3000/products#123')
':id/items/:item_id': 'item_show' (tag 'a' link 'localhost:3000/products#123/items/456')
```

Note: all tag a have data-ajax = 'false' and have some config:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function() {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
      });
```

The error happen when I'm in page 'localhost/products#123' and click tag 'a' link 'localhost:3000/products#123/items/456' . It alert 'Error Loading Page' then url auto change to 'localhost:3000/123/items/456' and in console have error: 'GET localhost:3000/123/items/456 404 (Not Found) '

My routes file:

```
class Braindu.Routers.Mobile extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @products = new Braindu.Collections.Products()
    @products_view = new Braindu.Views.MobileProductsIndex(collection: @products, id_product_el:'product-index-page')

  routes:
    ''    : 'product_index'
    ':id' : 'product_show'
    ':id/items/:item_id': 'item_show'


  product_index: ->
    @product_index_view.render()

  product_show:(id) ->
    $.mobile.changePage( "#product-show-page" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } )
    current_product_model = @product_index_view.product_collection.where({_id: id})[0]
    if current_product_model != null && current_product_model != undefined
      @product_index_view.render_current_product(current_product_model)

  item_show:(id, item_id)->
    console.log 'item showwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww'
    $.mobile.changePage( "#object-card-page" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } )
```

Comment: please share your routing code as well as where you are making the GET call.

Comment: I add func route. please see it

Answer (score 0):

When you call localhost:3000/123/items/456 are you calling the below function ?

```
 product_show:(id) ->
    $.mobile.changePage( "#product-show-page" , { reverse: false, changeHash: false } )
    current_product_model = @product_index_view.product_collection.where({_id: id})[0]
    if current_product_model != null && current_product_model != undefined
      @product_index_view.render_current_product(current_product_model)
```

if so please debug and find out the value of id for me please.

Thank you

Comment: The error happen when I'm in page 'localhost/products#123' and click tag 'a' with href 'localhost:3000/products#123/items/456'.
It not go to item_show function.
The product_show func is work fine, id value is: 123

Comment: Try to follow this answer but still get error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870948/how-to-get-this-backbone-route-to-work?rq=1

Comment: are you using navigate property at all to navigate ?      appFsMvc.App.navigate( "create", { trigger: true } );

Comment: I don't know what navigate using for . I just call Backbone.history.start(). And I using gem 'backbone-on-rails'

Comment: I add route:  'test'(localhost:3000/products#test) is run ok. but 'test/abc' (localhost:3000/products#test/abc) is error like above. Did I missing some config for backbone or for mobile??

Comment: Ahh, I remove jquery.history it work fine in PC. So error is some missing or wrong config jquery mobile. Please take a look at mobile init above and tell me if you find some thing wrong. Thanks :D

Comment: Finaly, Remove jquery.history.js, update version jquery.mobile.js, and place config before require jquery.mobile. It run fine now. Thank you very much @codeinzone. :) :) :)